# iMessage Security / Video Conferencing

Tags: messages

Remember how on iChat you could block certain people or just allow certain people? Is there a way to do that on iMessage?

Comment: Are you asking about iMessage as a service for iOS and OS X, or the Messages app on OS X?

Comment: I edited this to have one question. Feel free to ask the second question as a new stand-alone query.

Answer (score 0):

Why not try [CUMeeting video conferencing software](http://www.cumeeting.com) which allows multiple people in the same conference.